# Asymptotic Run Time Analysis -- Coin Change Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, asymptotic-complexity, coin-change

I need help finding the Asymptotic run time, i.e. Big O(n), of the following algorithm--> change_slow() .  I've tried masters method and other techniques but can't seem to find the answer.

This is a coin change problem, processed with the following ranges of data:

```
for i in range(50, 950, 50):
    data.append(([1,10,25,50],i))

for i in range(50, 600, 50):
     data.append(([1,3,4,17,31],i))
```

Here is the algorithm:

```
coins = item[0]
amount = item[1]

coins_needed = [j for j in change_slow(amount, coins, [])]


def change_slow(a, v, c):
    if(len(v) == 0):
        pass
    elif(sum(c) == a):
        yield c
    elif(sum(c) > a):
        pass
    else:
        for i in change_slow(a, v[:], c + [v[0]]):
            yield i
        for i in change_slow(a, v[1:], c):
            yield i
```

What would be the equation in form of  T(n) = ?

Comment: 1. To analyze run time, it would be helpful to just write a pseudo code. Or at least, remove the fancy "yield" things, and use return only. 2. If you have get the recurrence expression of T(n), please also write out; mathematically, we can always write the recursion tree and make a good guess.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm even close, but I'm getting t(n) = 4T(n-1)+n

Comment: If this is true, then T(n) = O(4^n)

Comment: I have run experimental analysis on my results and when I graph the results and calculate line regression I get either:

Comment: DATA: Coins [1,10,25,50], Range: 50-950
Exponential Line Equation: 
y = 0.0057e0.0096x
R2 = 0.91993

Power Line Equation: 
y = 6E-10x3.4887
R² = 0.99259

Comment: DATA: Coins[1,3,4,17,31], Range: 50-600,

Exponential Line Equation: 
y = 0.0433e0.018x
R² = 0.93459

Power Line Equation: 
y = 3E-10x4.4228
R² = 0.9947

Comment: T(n) = O(4^n) doesn't means T(n) = c * 4^n. In fact, it means: exists n0 > 0, c > 0, for any n >= n0, T(n) <= c * 4^n. It's not helpful to measure run time and draw plots.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to give you an exact answer (the recurrence relation), but you can find it experimentally by counting the # of steps while varying the input.

```
steps = 0

def change_slow(a, v, c):
    global steps
    steps += 1
    if(len(v) == 0):
        pass
    elif(sum(c) == a):
        yield c
    elif(sum(c) > a):
        pass
    else:
        for i in change_slow(a, v[:], c + [v[0]]):
            yield i
        for i in change_slow(a, v[1:], c):
            yield i

print "\n== Varying number of coins =="

for i in range(1, 40):
    coins = range(1, i+1)
    result = list(change_slow(19, coins, []))
    print "%s\t%s" % (len(coins), steps)
    steps = 0

print "\n== Varying the amount =="

for i in range(1, 1000):
    result = list(change_slow(i, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], []))
    print "%s\t%s" % (i, steps)
    steps = 0
```

Graphing this data:

https://plot.ly/~skryskalla/11

Increasing the number of coins causes a linear increase in # of steps, and increasing the amount gives an exponential increase in # of steps.

Comment: Do you have an idea on what the T(n) would be?  Thanks for the explanation btw!